# Trouble installing pyGObject on python3

Tags: python

I keep getting error messages while trying to install PyGObject on python3 (Mac OS X 10.9)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
 File "/private/var/folders/zh/hww3rvgx1rg62zwc8ct51r1r0000gn/T/pip-build-v5qjvi2y/pygobject/setup.py", line 272
   raise SystemExit, 'ERROR: Nothing to do, gio could not be found and is essential.'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zh/hww3rvgx1rg62zwc8ct51r1r0000gn/T/pip-build-v5qjvi2y/pygobject
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a python2 module with python 3. The syntax error occurs because there has been a change to the syntax for raising an exception. `raise SystemExit, 'Message'` has become `raise SystemExit('Message')`

You should make sure that you have the python3 versions of the module.